# Constructing a Linear List Insert Method

Tags: c#, list

I'm not sure how to implement a Linked List Insert method. I know I need to create a new node() iterate through the list and I know how to do that but I'm not sure how insertion works, it isn't as simple as an array.

Wondered if anyone could possibly help out and explain how I'd construct a method like this.

Comment: I meant *Linked* list, sorry. will add psuedocode in a second, trying to sort out the relevant code.

Comment: Something like `public Node InsertAfter(object value, Node after)`, but it all pretty much depends on what the rest of your code looks like and what you want the method to do exactly. If you want us to explain how a linked list works _and_ how to implement one, I'd suggest closing this question as "Too Broad". Show what you have tried and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: Its simplier than an array because you do not have to care about resizing, simply reset the next-pointer of the previous element to the inserted element, and the next-pointer of the inserted element to that one where the previous one pointed to before.

Comment: Look at how its implemented in the frameworks [`LinkedList<T>`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/linkedlist.cs,c689a31d05a0c93e)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to make a sample. Maybe you'll find it handy

```
using System;
namespace LinkedList
{
    class LinkedList
    {

        public static void Main(String[] args){
            var list = new LinkedList();

            list.Insert (1);
            list.Insert (2);
            list.Insert (3);
            list.Insert (4);

            var node = list.Head;
            do {
                Console.Out.WriteLine (node.Value);

            } while((node = node.Next) != null);
        }

        private Node _dummy;
        private Node _head;
        private Node _tail;

        public Node Head { get { return _head; }}

        public LinkedList(){
            _dummy = new Node(null, null);
            _head = _dummy;
            _tail = _dummy;
        }

        public void Insert(int value){
            _head = new Node(_head, value);
        }

        public class Node{

            public int? Value { get; set; }
            public Node Next { get; set;}

            public Node(Node next, int? value){
                Value = value;
                Next = next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Node head;
    object key;
    Node nodeTobeInserted;

    void Insert(object key)
    {
      if(head == null)
        head = new Node();
      else if(head.value.Equals(key))
      {
       Node next = head.Next;
       head=nodeToBeInserted;
       head.Next = next;
      }
      else
      {
       do
       {
           Node next = head.next;

       }
       while(next.Next != null && next.Next.value != key);
       if(next.Next !=null)
         {
           nodeTobeInserted.Next = node.Next;
           node.Next = nodeToBeInserted;
         }

        }

    }

    // Sample Code, but yeah this might give you an idea how to do it
```